# Angular2 Tabs and Routes

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Is there a way to open each of the anchro click (for example from menu) in a separate tabs in angular?
  Instead of opening all routes in same router-outlet.?
I tried named router-outlet but child sub routes are not working seamlessly as supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular router only adds components to `<router-outlet>`, you can use plain JS to open new tabs.

A new tab is a new different SPA application. Angular2 is for SPA, therefore one Angular2 application can't be run spread over multiple tabs.